# Rspec having difficulty testing #create with build controller method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

So if your #create controller method is simply:

```
@testimonial = Testimonial.new(testimonial_params)
```

And you test it in your specs like so:

testimonials_controller_spec.rb

```
describe "POST #create" do 
    context "with VALID attributes" do 
        it "creates new testimonial" do 
            expect {
                    post :create, testimonial: FactoryGirl.attributes_for(:testimonial)
            }.to change(Testimonial, :count).by(1)
        end
    end
end
```

It works fine. The code:

```
post :create, testimonial: FactoryGirl.attributes_for(:testimonial)
```

is correct.

However, in my TestimonialsController, my create method is actually:

```
@testimonial = current_user.testimonials.build(testimonial_params)
```

My rspec method doesn't work with this. What should I use instead of:

```
post :create, testimonial: FactoryGirl.attributes_for(:testimonial)
```

?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sign in the user before calling the controller action. Please find the following:

```
#testimonials_controller_spec.rb 
require 'rails_helper' 
describe TestimonialsController, type: :controller do

  let(:user) do
    FactoryGirl.create :user
  end

  before do
    sign_in user
  end

  describe "POST #create" do 
    context "with VALID attributes" do 
      it "creates new testimonial" do 
        expect {
          post :create, testimonial:    FactoryGirl.attributes_for(:testimonial)
        }.to change(Testimonial, :count).by(1)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks! I hadn't tried sign_in because I previously had had problems with Devise helpers, so I had assumed it wouldn't work. I gave it a shot this time, expecting it not to work, but it did. Must have been something I was doing wrong when trying to use the Devise helpers with a different spec.

Comment: In this particular case, I ended up just doing sign_in FactoryGirl.create(:student), which worked. QUESTION: how would I simulate a signed-in user without using the Devise helper?

Answer (score -1):

Build doesn't save/persist the record to the database. Why not make it:

```
@testimonial = current_user.testimonials.new(testimonial_params)
@testimonial.save
```

Comment: Well, it works in the browser in development and in production! Testimonials save and are displayed no problem.

Comment: I'm not sure but I think it has to be build so the testimonials are indexed by the user id.

Comment: (testimonials belong_to users and users have_many testimonials)